# Как передать значения из DOM элементов в обработчик на JS?

Tags: php, javascript, html, post

Вопрос достаточно банальный, но нужна ваша помощь.

есть страничка, в неё из базы подгружаются контакты. Сам контакт выглядит вот так `

```
<div class="ui cards cardsWrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="' + array[i].id + '" class="right floated">' + array[i].id + '</div>
            <div contenteditable="true" class="header">' + array[i].title + '</div>
            <div contenteditable="true" class="meta">' + array[i].who + '</div>
        </div>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content">' + array[i].description + '</div>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content">' + array[i].housing + '</div>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content"> ' + array[i].location + '</div>
        <div class="extra content center aligned"><button class="ui green button write_changes">Записать</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

таких 300 шт. Я сделал их поля редактируемыми, но теперь не могу понять как передать изменения в обработчик, 300 кнопок "Записать", как отличить какая была нажата, чтобы передать отредактированные поля именно с той карточки, где эта кнопка находится? Если отслеживать через класс кнопки `write_changes`, то все поля со всех карточек будут перезаписаны, как мне кажется. Представить можно следующим образом, в Exel есть ячейки, если изменить ячейку и нажать сохранить, то все ок, здесь же кнопка сохранить под каждой карточкой.

Comment: чистый js или jquery? вы имеете ввиду как отправить ajax post запрос через js на php файл?

Comment: нет как отправить я знаю, вопрос в том как при  изменении полей карточки, понять что кнопка записать была нажата именно в этой карточке, а не в другой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, самый ли это правильный способ. Я бы повесил ОДИН обработчик на родительский элемент для ВСЕХ карточек. Это может быть wrapper или даже `body`. Примерно так:

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
wrapper.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let parent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
  console.log(e.target); // в e.target элемент по которому кликнули. 
  console.log(parent); //
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ui cards cardsWrapper">
      <div class="card first-card">
          <div class="content">
              <div id="1" class="right floated">id</div>
              <div contenteditable="true" class="header">title</div>
              <div contenteditable="true" class="meta">who</div>
          </div>
          <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content">description</div>
          <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content">housing</div>
          <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content">location</div>
          <div class="extra content center aligned"><button class="ui green button write_changes">Записать</button></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui cards cardsWrapper">
    <div class="card second-card" >
        <div class="content">
            <div id="2" class="right floated">id</div>
            <div contenteditable="true" class="header">title</div>
            <div contenteditable="true" class="meta">who</div>
        </div>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content">description</div>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content">housing</div>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content">location</div>
        <div class="extra content center aligned"><button class="ui green button write_changes">Записать</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui cards cardsWrapper">
    <div class="card third-card">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="3" class="right floated">id</div>
            <div contenteditable="true" class="header">title</div>
            <div contenteditable="true" class="meta">who</div>
        </div>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content">description</div>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content">housing</div>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="extra content">location</div>
        <div class="extra content center aligned"><button class="ui green button write_changes">Записать</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а что принимает функция?? Что знаит "e"?

Comment: функция принимает event (событие). Можете его назвать как угодно, просто принято так

Comment: Получается мне нужно каждую кнопку обернуть в div, добавить ей кастомный атрибут типа вашего data-id, после повесить обработчик на весь документ и отлавливать изменения?

Comment: можете ничего из этого не делать. А просто повесить обработчик на родительсикй элемент. А что бы получить доступ к `<div class="card">` элемента у которого сработало событие - можете сделать так: let parent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;

Comment: не понял(, может есть ссылка где почитать?

Comment: @BoBo Сейчас я изменю пример, посмотите

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66084/discussion-between-igor-lut-and-bobo).